# SpriteKit Buttons stay pressed

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I've made two buttons (leftBtn and rightBtn). They work fine when pressing and depressing.. However, when you press and hold, then move your finger away from the button and depress, the button stays down?

Here is the code for both touchDown and touchUp

```
func touchDown(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {
    let rightBtn = childNode(withName: "rightBtn");
    let leftBtn = childNode(withName: "leftBtn");

    if(rightBtn?.frame.contains(pos) == true){
        right = true;
    }
    else if(leftBtn?.frame.contains(pos) == true){
        left = true;
    }
}

func touchMoved(toPoint pos : CGPoint) {

}

func touchUp(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {
    let rightBtn = childNode(withName: "rightBtn");
    let leftBtn = childNode(withName: "leftBtn");

    if(rightBtn?.frame.contains(pos) == true){
        right = false;
        carController.stopMove();
    }
    else if(leftBtn?.frame.contains(pos) == true){
        left = false;
        carController.stopMove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button stays down because the touch up (i.e. finger moving up and away from the screen) doesn't occur on the button anymore. Instead, it occurs on some other part of your view. If you want the button to not remain pressed, consider adding code to the touchesMoved method too.